# What is the different between vault vs snapshot and vault in azure backups

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

I have the following question when backing up VMs using Azure Backup there are two types of recovery - Snapshot and Vault & Vault. What is the difference between those? 
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-instant-restore-capability#if-the-recovery-type-for-a-restore-point-is-snapshot-and-vault-and-i-perform-a-restore-operation-which-recovery-type-will-be-used) they mention at least this:

> If the recovery type for a restore point is “Snapshot and vault” and I perform a restore operation, which recovery type will be used?
>
> If the recovery type is “snapshot and vault”, restore will be automatically done from the local snapshot, which will be much faster compared to the restore done from the vault.

So this seems to be related to the Instant Restore feature.

Snapshot and Vault means there is a local snapshot in your storage account, and is faster to restore from.
The ones with Vault are slower as it needs to be pulled from the vault.

By default, these snapshots are kept for 2 days.